# UserForm vanishes when clicking ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

First I’m a novice.  I’ve been reading, experimenting, and Googling to get this far, but haven’t found anything that helps me understand this.

I’m trying to build a UserForm to collect range data.  It’s part of a data centralization effort to add data to “history” workbooks, processing them to track changes and update current interpretations if they’ve changed. The sources vary, but are large and consistent enough to be worth the effort to automate.

Also, I work on am isolated (closed) network so I’ve retyped my code, hopefully (mostly) correctly here.

My UserForm code is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim wb as Workbook, lastwb as Workbook

    For Each wb in Application.workbooks
        comboBox1.addItem wb.name
    next
    ComboBox1 = ActiveWorkbook.name
End sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
     If ComboBox1 <> "" then Application.Workbooks(ComboBox1.Text).Activate
     Label1.Caption = "": RefEdit1 = ""
End sub

Private Sub RefEdit1_Change()
    Label1.Caption = ""
    If RefEdit1.value <> "" then
    Label1.Caption = "[" & ComboBox1 & "]" & Replace(refEdit1, "!", "'!")
End sub
```

I’m calling it with

```
Private Sub addToHistory()
Dim range1 as range
Dim … 'other variables and code

With New Userform
   .Show
   range1 = .label
   .Hide
   Unload Userform1

Debug.Print range1
… 'other code to close/save my workbooks
End Sub
```

Whenever I try to click on my combo box it vanishes.  Even marking every line in the UserForm code for debugging, it simply vanishes leaving me with no clue what happened or how to prevent it.

Comment: What is `ComboBox1.Test`?

Comment: A typo for ComboBox1.Text.  Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Is **If RefEdit`.value <> "" then** also a typo then? This should show up as red in the editor.

Comment: Yes.  Updated.   It should have been If RefEdit1.value <> "" then

Comment: Did you have these typos in your code? Does it work now? What exatcly is happening and when?

Comment: The `RefEdit` control is [notoriously unreliable](https://peltiertech.com/unspecified-painfully-frustrating-error/)

Comment: I retyped the code here from a printout.  When I run the code, addToHistory() reaches the  segment included above.  At the .Show line it transitions to UserForm_Initialize() then ComboBox1_Change() before the UserForm is visible.  If I interact with he ComboBox in any way, the UserForm vanishes.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I'm open to suggestions.   I'm a simple plagiarizer of other answers that, from the comments and what I can read of the syntax, do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is there a chance that it triggers `.Hide`? I find it strange to have `.Show` and `.Hide` after each other in the first place but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: With my level of knowledge I won't rule it out.  I don't think I'm calling it even unintentionally though.  I don't have '.Hide' in the UserForm code.  Also, I have debug stops and have been stepping through each step as well.  I have the expected pause to interact with the UserForm and pressing F8 after it vanishes only restarts addToHistory() vice printing my 'Debug.Print range1' before proceeding to 'Unload UserForm1'.

Comment: fyi see [Alternative to RefEdit Control](https://peltiertech.com/refedit-control-alternative/) @Revman

Comment: @revam re _I'm open to suggestions_ I've given you a suggestion (a little  obliquely I'll admit) - don't use Refedit.  You'll find plenty of alternatives if you do a little research